# Filters in URL using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-string

I am trying to filter results from a database on a page where the user can pick none of more filters.

I have:

```
...
$out .= '<a class="filter-link" href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&age='.$ageId.'">';
...
```

The problem with this is that obviously it will keep appending the same thing to the query string i.e.

```
?page=1&&age=3&age=3&age=1&age=6
```

How can I get this to work properly using Laravel?

Comment: How is your site built? Do you select all these filters on the same page? Maybe use checkboxes?

Comment: Maybe [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) can help you?

Comment: Thanks, would it be better to instead link every filter to the same controller put passing something like age=3 and append it to a session variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$params = Input::get();
$params['age'] = 'something';  # overwrite the age that was in the URL (if any)
$params = http_build_query($params);

$out .= '<a class="filter-link" href="'.[THE_PAGE_URL].'?'.$params">';
```

Note that [THE_PAGE_URL] should be in its base form without any query string parameters in it as you'll be appending them all again using $params.

**Edit in response to your comment:**

> This keeps appending the same params to the query string each time the
>   link is clicked.

Say your user arrives at a URL like:

http://example.com/some/route?page=3&age=6&color=red

If you want a link that forgets all the current parameters and only specifies age:

```
$out .= '<a class="filter-link" href="'.URL::to("some/route").'?age=5">';
```

The above should result in:  http://example.com/some/route?age=5

Or, if you want a link that keeps the current color filter (red) but changes the age parameter and forgets the page parameter entirely:

```
$params = Input::except('page');  # get all current parameters except page...
$params['age'] = '5';  # overwrite the age parameter that was in the URL (if any)
$params = http_build_query($params);  # should return "color=red&age=5"

$out .= '<a class="filter-link" href="'.URL::to('some/route').'?'.$params">';
```

The above should result in:  http://example.com/some/route?color=red&age=5

Hope that helps.

Comment: This keeps appending the same params to the query string each time the link is clicked.

Comment: @imperium2335 Please see my edited answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

use [**http_build_query**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
$out .= '<a class="filter-link" href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET).'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4, you can use the **Request** class to build URLs. *Request::url()* strips out the query parameters and *Request::fullUrl()* includes them. Your code would look like this:

```
$out .= '<a class="filter-link" href="'.Request::url().'?age='.$ageId.'">';
```

If you need to append the *page* parameter (if it exists), then use *http_build_query*:

```
$params['age'] = $ageId;
$params['page'] = Input::get('page');
$out .= '<a class="filter-link" href="'.Request::url().'?'.http_build_query($params).'">';
```